# Is it okay to write "Could I please get a piece of paper?

Tags: modal-verbs

Does could make the use of please redundant?

Which sentence is grammatically correct

Could I have piece of paper? or
Could I please have a piece of paper? or 
Could I have a piece of paper, please?

Comment: Could I have a piece of paper, please? - OK. Could I have a piece of paper? - OK.

Comment: Could I get a piece of paper, please? - also OK.

Comment: Hi Saad, and welcome to ELL. If you haven't already, check out the tour. Remember, you're only supposed to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

No, "could" doesn't make the use of "please" redundant. It's true that "Could I have a piece of paper?" is more polite than "Can I have a piece of paper?", but "Could I please have a piece of paper?" is even more polite.

"Could I please have a piece of paper?" and "Could I have a piece of paper, please?" are of equal politeness and are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is a difference between the sentences

- *Could I have a piece of paper?*
- *Could I get a piece of paper?*

In the second, you are asking to get a piece of paper yourself. In the first, the manner of getting the paper (getting it yourself or having it given to you) is not explicitly specified, but most likely you would like it given to you.